# How to get the remaining disk space on remote linux servers via node app

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

Have have several droplets on digitalocean and I want to get the remaining disk space on each of them from a node application running on one server to save to a database. I know how to get this info from a remote terminal via the commmand

```
df -h --output=pcent "/dev/vda1"
```

but are looking for a solution from the node app. All servers are connected via a vpn but I'm not familar with a way to acheive this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like SSH remoting would be a gold way. Or use ansible for this or an a Prometheus exporter like node exporter

Comment: Through a node.js app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

[Live demo](https://repl.it/@HBAMITHKUMARA/MadeupSpitefulRom)

On server side in nodejs

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

function getDiskSpace() {

  var dir = "/dev/vda1";
  var cmd = "df -h --output=pcent " + dir;

  exec(cmd, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      // Error handling
      console.log("ERROR", err);
    } else {
      // Sucess response handling
      console.log("SUCCESS", data);
    }
  });

}
```

Reference

[Node - child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect for my use case :)